# node app instance name when running via pm2 cluster

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have backend node app, that is run by pm2 in cluster mode.
I'm running fixed 2 instances.

Is there a way to identify instance name or number from within executed app?

App name is "test", I would like to get from within the app "test 1" and "test 2" for given instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to use two environment variables set by pm2:

- `process.env.pm_id` is automatically set to the instance id (`0`, `1`, ...).
- `process.env.name` is set to the app name (in your case `test`).

Answer (score 0):

pm2 gives you 3 env params in this case:

1. `process.env.name` (gives name of process)
2. `process.env.pm_id` (gives process id)
3. `process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE` (gives instance id for specific process, more about [NODE_APP_INSTANCE](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/))

In case of clustering in multiple processes, a combination of any of 1/2, and 3 works.

Answer (score -1):

While starting the pm2 set the name as:
`pm2 start app.js --name test`